# Practice of exit(0) in C and System.exit(0) in Java

Tags: java, android, c, garbage-collection, exit

To use `exit(0)` in C is not a good practice, if there are alternatives, since it does not free resources for example. But to use `System.exit(0)` in Java - how is it here? Could one trust the garbage collector in this context?

C language:

```
 exit(0);
```

Java:

```
 System.exit(0)
```

Comment: Why do you care about garbage collection if you are about to kill the application?

Comment: It's irrelevant - you're about to kill the application. That will free all of the memory. So why care about garbage collection?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis - Nope! In Java android you KILL the Activity, not necerarilly the app

Comment: @user2991252 When you kill an activity in Android, the OS handles the memory management.  It's not up to the programmer.

Comment: In most operating systems, you wouldn't have to worry in either case. However, there are resources other than memory to worry about: Shared memory segments, mutexes / semaphores, sockets, etc. Those aren't always handled by exit(0) in C, but I can't speak for Java.

Comment: Does not free *what* resources? The last operating system I used that didn't free all process resources on exit was NetWare 3 in about 1993.

Comment: Android is a rather different beast in this respect. Are you actually wanting to know about how this is handled in Android apps?

Comment: "To use exit(0) in C is not a good practice" - this is news to me - can you provide a reference?

Answer (score 2):

> But to use System.exit(0) in java - how is it here? Could one trust the garbage-collector in this context?

When you call `System.exit` in Java, the garbage collector is not normally run<sup>1</sup>.  However, in any JVM that I've ever heard of, there is something else that reclaims all of the objects that were allocated.  (Typically it is handled at the operating system level.)

The fact that the GC doesn't run is only significant if you are relying on object finalizers to so something important before the JVM terminates.

Hypothetically, if your Java application used JNI (etc) to call native methods, then those methods could access system resources that might be problematic.  However:

1. As a general rule the operating system *does* take care of such things.  At least it does for modern versions of Linux and UNIX, AFAIK.
2. The garbage collector has no knowledge of those resources anyway.  If the OS can't reclaim them, then the Java garbage collector won't help.

If you did need to clean up such resources acquired by a Java program (via native code) then the best approach would be to implement the cleanup in native code methods, and use a "shutdown hook" to run them.  The shutdown hooks will be run if you call `System.exit`.

---

<sup>1 - A garbage collection will be performed on JVM exit if you have previously called `runFinalizersOnExit(true)`.  However, this is a **deprecated** method.  The Oracle site explains it like this:</sup>

> <sup>Q: Why is Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit deprecated?</sup>
>
> <sup>A: Because it is inherently unsafe. It may result in finalizers being called on live objects while other threads are concurrently manipulating those objects, resulting in erratic behavior or deadlock. While this problem could be prevented if the class whose objects are being finalized were coded to "defend against" this call, most programmers do not defend against it. They assume that an object is dead at the time that its finalizer is called.</sup>
>
> <sup>Further, the call is not "thread-safe" in the sense that it sets a VM-global flag. This forces every class with a finalizer to defend against the finalization of live objects!</sup>

<sup>In short, this is a dangerous approach, and it won't directly deal with the kind of resources that the OP is worried about.</sup>

Comment: In general, it does, yes, but often System V IPC objects will remain after process termination unless you take special effort to clean them up. I've hit the Linux kernel limit on shared memory sections before when a program I was working on core dumped several times in a row while I was debugging / fixing it. The same can happen with message queues and semaphores. See the man pages for ipcs and ipcrm on Linux.

Comment: _"When you call `System.exit` in Java, the garbage collector is not run."_ -- This can be wrong in Android. From [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#exit%28int%29): _"If runFinalizersOnExit(boolean) has been previously invoked with a true argument, then **all objects will be properly garbage-collected** and finalized first."_ (emphasis added)

Comment: @TedHopp - On Java SE (at least) that method is deprecated.  However, I have added that information as a footnote.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this. In C, you are building your source code into a binary file that will execute on it's own only conforming to the rules of logical programming and the rules set by your OS. The OS however does not manage your memory for you. It handles events and sends information to the hardware that tell it how to run, nothing more, nothing less. In java, all code is compiled into java's own bytecode. Upon execution it does not actually at any time communicate to the OS. The virtual machine designed to run that bytecode is what does the talking. When you call System.exit (0), you are telling the virtual machine that the app you are running is coming to a halt, from there the machine handles IT'S OWN MEMORY which just so happens to include anything you did not already remove via the garbage collector but only if the VM is exiting as well. Hope that helps